# shiny: plot a graph from source file dependent on input

Tags: r, graph, shiny

So I am trying out shiny, and I have a problem.

What I want is a selectinput were you can select the different option and get a certain graph. These different graphs are ggplot2 graphs that are already created in a source file. So the graphs only have to be called. However I do not seem to figure out how to do that. The graphs are ggplot2 graphs and they are fine, they load perfectly, so I assume that that is not the problem.

I also want to have a text output that depends on the selectinput.

So here is my server script:

```
shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {
    output$map <- renderPlot({
      plot <- switch(input$activity, 
                    "" = NULL,
                    "act1" = plot1,
                    "act2" = plot2,
                    "act3" = plot3,
                    "act4" = plot4,
                    "act5" = plot5,
                    "act6" = plot6)
     plot
   }),
   output$text1 <- renderText({ 
     text <- switch(input$Activiteit, 
            "" = NULL,
            "act1" = paste("blabla"),
            "act2" = paste("blabla2"),
            "act3" = paste("blabla3"),
            "act4" = paste("blabla4"),
            "act5" = paste("blabla5"),
            "act6" = paste("blabla6")
            )
     text
   })

 }
 )
```

One thing were I am not certain about is were I have to load the source file. I now load it in the main file were you run the App. I can also understand that you have to load it in the server file.

However that is not the only problem because the text is also not showing in the shiny output. So the must be something wrong with my code. The ui script gives the right output, so that is not the problem. I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.Hi, you dont need a comma between 2 outputs in server.R and you dont need `"" = NULL,` in `switch`. Try this example :

```
## ui.R
shinyUI(fluidPage(
selectInput(inputId = "Activiteit", label = "", choices = c("", paste0("act", 1:6))),
h2("Your text"),
textOutput(outputId = "text1"),
h2("Your graph"),
plotOutput(outputId = "map")
))

## server.R
shinyServer(
function(input, output) {
   output$map <- renderPlot({
     p <- switch(input$Activiteit, 
                 "act1" = p1,
                 "act2" = p2,
                 "act3" = p3,
                 "act4" = p4,
                 "act5" = p5,
                 "act6" = p6)
    print(p)
  })
  # no comma here
  output$text1 <- renderText({ 
   text <- switch(input$Activiteit, 
                 "act1" = paste("blabla"),
                 "act2" = paste("blabla2"),
                 "act3" = paste("blabla3"),
                 "act4" = paste("blabla4"),
                 "act5" = paste("blabla5"),
                 "act6" = paste("blabla6")
  )
  return(text)
  })

  }
 )

## global.R
# you can source files here
library(ggplot2)
p1 <- qplot(1:10, rnorm(10), colour = runif(10))
p2 <- qplot(1:20, rnorm(20), colour = runif(20))
p3 <- qplot(1:30, rnorm(30), colour = runif(30))
p4 <- qplot(1:40, rnorm(40), colour = runif(40))
p5 <- qplot(1:50, rnorm(50), colour = runif(50))
p6 <- qplot(1:60, rnorm(60), colour = runif(60))
```

Hope it helps.